# Serving django with nginx and uWSGI

Tags: python, django, nginx, uwsgi

I followed [this post](https://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.org/en/latest/tutorials/Django_and_nginx.html) to serve my django project. The project runs well with `manage.py runserver` and I want to set it up for production. Here are my setting files:

`nginx.conf`:

```
upstream django {
    server /tmp/vc.sock;
    #server 10.9.1.137:8002;
}

server {
    listen      8001;
    server_name 10.9.1.137;
    charset     utf-8;
    client_max_body_size 25M;

    location /media  {
        alias /home/deploy/vc/media;
    }
    location /static {
        alias /home/deploy/vc/static;
    }


    location / {
        uwsgi_pass  django;
        include     /etc/nginx/uwsgi_params;
    }
}
```

`uwsgi.ini`:

```
[uwsgi]

chdir           = /home/deploy/vc
wsgi-file      = vc/wsgi.py

master          = true
processes       = 2
#socket          = :8002
socket          = /tmp/vc.sock
chmod-socket    = 666
vacuum          = true
```

If I use TCP port socket (`server 10.9.1.137:8002` and `socket = :8002`), it's going to be fine. However if I comment them out and use Unix sockets(`server /tmp/vc.sock` and `socket = /tmp/vc.sock`), the server will return 502 error. How should I fix it?

`EDIT`

Here's the nginx error log when I run `/etc/init.d/nginx restart`

```
nginx: [emerg] invalid host in upstream "/tmp/vc.sock" in /etc/nginx/conf.d/vc.conf:2
nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test failed
```

And this is the warning when I run `uwsgi --ini vc/uwsgi.ini`:

```
*** WARNING: you are running uWSGI as root !!! (use the --uid flag) ***
```

Can't I run uWSGI as root?

Answer (score 5):

roberto's comment should be an answer!

> the syntax in nginx for unix socket path is wrong, you need to prefix
>   it with unix:

Answer (score 0):

Check your nginx error log, very probably is telling you it does not have permissions to the socket. Unix sockets honour file system permissions, so nginx must have write privilege over the socket file. Short answer: 664 is not enough, you need 666

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I changed to 666 but it's still the same. I edited my question and added the error log. Is it because I'm running as root?

Comment: the syntax in nginx for unix socket path is wrong, you need to prefix it with unix: